# MariaDB - Error log configuration?

Tags: mysql, logging, mariadb

I have MariaDB in my Debian 7 and would like to know why mysql suddenly stop. I should edit `my.cnf` and define the path of error log file.

According to [this](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/monitoring-mysql-the-error-log-2009-09-16/) I should put `log-error = /path/to/error/log` under `[mysqld_safe]` and `[mysqld]`.

But according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89228/mysql-log-confusion) I should put `log_error = /path/to/error/log` under `[mysqld]`.

So, which is the correct way? `log-error` or `log_error` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### log-error or log_error

`log-error` is the correct name to assign to when setting options in the options file `my.cnf`.

`log_error` is the correct system variable name when reading like `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%error%'`.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/optimization-and-tuning/system-variables/server-system-variables/#log
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-option-tables.html

### [mysqld_safe] or [mysqld]

It is sufficient to put it in any one of the two sections, `[mysqld_safe]` or `[mysqld]`. MariaDB and MySQL read both sections.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/getting-started/starting-and-stopping-mariadb/mysqld_safe/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld-safe.html

Answer (score 6):

1. Your variable is `log_error`, but you define `log-error;` all variables are with "_", not with "-". It had hit my head some time ago too. When I make it with `log_error` it starts correctly.
2. After you do correct the "-" to "_" , you must enter `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf` and comment the 2 lines:

   - `skip_log_error`
   - `syslog -> #skip_log_error #syslog`

   Otherwise errors will go to the syslog and you will wonder where they are. This file should been used only when there is "mysqld_safe" option used when starting mysqld, but in fact they are also used when you start normally. In mariadb 10.1.* these 2 lines are removed.

Comment: YES ... thank you so much. It's the solution... tnx again :)

Comment: I will never understand why programmers love to make everything so non-intuitive. Every normal config file is .CONF, here .CNF.  Variables with '-', but configuration with '_'. Nested configurations. Dozens places where you set something so standard as a silly log file that should be working by default (and it is not).

Thank you I stopped wandering and trying the most disparate solutions for HOURS. It works! Thanks!